# Error starting Activity from a Class on Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have the following class `SubMenuToolBar` which I usually instantiate from an activity (`MainActivity`) that passes itself (`this`) in the constructor upon instantiation:

```
public class SubMenuToolBar extends Activity {
        private android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar mToolbar;
        private Activity mActivity;
        RelativeLayout mLayout;

public SubToolbar(android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbar, Activity activity) {
            mActivity = activity;
            mToolbar = toolbar;
            mLayout = (RelativeLayout) mToolbar.findViewById(R.id.layout_toolbar);

            mLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(mActivity, UserMessagesActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

    }
```

**MainActivity.cs**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    new SubMenuToolBar ((android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.sub_toolbar), this);
    }
```

Everytime I click on the element registered with the click event handler (in the activity) I get the popular error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread android.app.ActivityThread.getApplicationThread()' on a null object reference

11-20 08:31:33.422 23802-23802/com.xxx.apps.xxx E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3918)
11-20 08:31:33.422 23802-23802/com.xxx .apps.xxx E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3877)
11-20 08:31:33.422 23802-23802/com.xxx.apps.xxx E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4200)
11-20 08:31:33.422 23802-23802/com.xxx.apps.xxx  E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4168)
11-20 08:31:33.422 23802-23802/com.xxx.apps.xxx E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.xxx.apps.xxx.SubMenuToolBar$1.onClick(SubToolbar.java:28)
```

I have tried using the Activity in the Intent, the Context of the activity, getApplicationContext, and getBaseContext. All throws the same error on line:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(mActivity, MessagesActivity.class);
```

I have checked SO and various web resource where most of them point to the activity need to be passed to the class so it's Context is used in the Intent, I have done that as you can see above and made sure all details of the calling Activity is passed and used, the problem is still there.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Explicit constructor in Activity? You should do initialization in OnCreate. Please read [HERE](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)

Comment: what is `mToolbarSub`??

Comment: Wrong name, sorry, corrected.

Comment: One does not simply "new" up an activity and expect it to work :). An activity has to be started the correct way (using intents for instance) so that its lifecycle is managed correctly by the framework. Your `new SubMenuToolBar ((android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.sub_toolbar), this);` is all kinds of wrong I believe. What you're trying to achieve is probably better done as a fragment (which can sometimes be seens as a `sub activity` or part of an activity).

Comment: Why you do it: `public class SubMenuToolBar extends Activity {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try replace this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mActivity, UserMessagesActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

to this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mActivity, UserMessagesActivity.class);
mActivity.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are a little confused. Activity must not be instantiated with `new`. You have to start it using `Intent`. There is two activities but I think you only need one.

```
public class SubMenuToolBar extends Activity {

    RelativeLayout mLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstance);
        setContentView(R.layout.your_activity_layout);

        android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar mToolbar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.sub_toolbar);

        mLayout = (RelativeLayout)mToolbar.findViewById(R.id.layout_toolbar);

        mLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(mActivity, UserMessagesActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        });
}
```

And use SubMenuToolBar as your main activity.

Comment: Not really, I want to encapsulate functions of the class work inside the class, I'm suing this all over the place, I wouldn't want to put all of the work (assigning toolbars, events, etc) every time I use this toolbar in an activity